# Not able to insert the lastmodifiedby by a userid in salesforce when importing through dataloader?

Tags: data-loader

What can be the possible reason?
The logged in user name is populating in LastModifiedBy

Already Enabled permission "Set/Create Audit field".

Comment: You should make sure to enable the permission Set Audit field both in : User Interface setting 'Set Audit Fields upon Record Creation" and "Update Records with Inactive Owners' and also in the profile level. Other then that, check if you have trigger or automation process that update the record after created from the data loader. in such case, it will change the last modified user that you entered from the data loader

Comment: Can you please double check if the UserId that has given in the lastModifiedBy is available in the Target org or not.